# How to configure Azure-DevOps release pipeline task to kick off automated UI test scripts on xcode in MacBook?

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xcuitest, azure-devops-server-2019

I have setup the Build pipeline in Azure-DevOps to generate build of xcode automation project. For that, I have used Microsoft hosted MacOS agent on my macbook. Now, i want to setup release pipeline to kick off automated test scripts from TFS/Azure-DevOps Server on the same macBook? Not sure what are the configuration I need to use in release pipeline task. If someone has done this, could you please help me step-by-step?

Comment: Check out `osascript`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want the automated test from azure devops to run against your local macBook.
If this is your intention. You may need to setup a self-hosted macOS agent on you local macBook.

Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops) to create a self-hosted agent.

And in the release pipeline, associate your release pipeline to the build artifacts from your build pipeline. Make sure the build artifacts include your test code.If not you may need to add a **publish artifact task** in your build pipeline to include your test code in the build artifacts which will be downloaded and used in release pipeline.

In your stage create an agent job with the **agent pool** set to your **agent pool** with your self-host agent. And add a xcode task to run your test. When you run the release pipeline the test will run on your local macBook.

[image]

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops) is documents about how to build, test and deploy with xcode. Hope you find above helpful.